# Count values, keep duplicates with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataset of ID's, in column A of GUID's (250,000 values). I need to count the amount of times each GUID in that column appears and then include that as another column within the data set. The problem is using .value_counts() with pandas gives me a list but removes the duplicates. As I want to align the new count dataset with the old one, the lists don't align.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

path = (r"D:\\Users\\cdoyle\Desktop\\Final2_.xlsx")
df = pd.read_excel(path)
df = df[['Data BoundingBoxGUID', 'Data Line', 'Data Remove Item:', 'Data Status:', 'Model']]
df2 = df['Data BoundingBoxGUID'].value_counts()


df_output = pd.concat([df,df2], axis=1)
```

Comment: You need to join the result of `value_counts` with the original DF to copy it into all the rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We usually do `transform`

```
df['new'] = df.groupby('Data BoundingBoxGUID')['Data BoundingBoxGUID'].transform('count')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @WeNYoBen, would this line go before the df_output line?

Comment: @cd-6 yes , it is